# UndefinedVariableError when querying pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to create a graph by querying values in a pandas `DataFrame`.

In this line:

```
data1 = [np.array(df.query('type == i')['continuous']
         for i in ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4')]
```

I get the error:

```
UndefinedVariableError: name 'i' is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `i` in your query expression

```
df.query('type == i')
```

is literally just the string `'i'`. Since there are no extra enclosing quotes around it, pandas interprets it as the name of another column in your `DataFrame`, i.e. it looks for cases where

```
df['type'] == df['i']
```

Since there is no `i` column, you get an `UndefinedVariableError`.

It looks like you intended to query where the values in the `type` column are equal to the string variable named `i`, i.e. where

```
df['type'] == 'Type1'
df['type'] == 'Type2' # etc.
```

In this case you need to actually insert the string `i` into the query expression:

```
df.query('type == "%s"' % i)
```

The extra set of quotes are necessary if `'Type1'`, `'Type2'` etc. are *values* within the `type` column, but not if they are the names of other columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Hi ali_m, I must be missing something in your explanation. Apologies, I am still very new at this! This line now looks like this: 

    data1 = [np.array(df.query('type == %s' %type)    ['continous']) for i in ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4')

It tells me that Type1 is undefined. Type1 is a value within column 'type.' What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, that's partly my fault - it wasn't clear whether `'Type1'`, `'Type2'` etc. were values in the `type` column or the names of other columns. In the former case you also need to enclose the string value in quotes within the expression: `df.query('type == "%s"' % i)`

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me. I am still struggling with this. Would you be able to post a full line example? My line now looks like this:
data1 = [np.array(df.query('type == "%s"' %Type1 %Type2 %Type3 %Type4)['continuous'])] and I still get the same error that Type1 is undefined.

Comment: No. `i` is the *name* of a string variable, whose *value* will change from `'Type1'` to `'Type2'` etc. as you iterate over the tuple of strings. On each loop iteration you want to insert the *current value* of the variable `i` into the query string, hence `df.query('type == "%s"' % i) for i in ('Type1', 'Type2', ..., )`

Comment: That did it! I have another error further down that I will try and solve now, but this definitely answered my question. Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: No need to construct a string format. Just use double quotes `df.query('type == "i"' )`

Answer (score 2):

I know too late but maybe it helps somebody - use double quotes for i 
`data1 = [np.array(df.query('type == "i"')['continuous']`

Answer (score 2):

```
data1 = [np.array(df.query('type == @i')['continuous']
     for i in ('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4')]
```

use '@' to refer variables

please refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), which writes:

> You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with
> an ‘@’ character like @a + b.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Thanks for your suggestion. I have add the link to the documentation.